# Angular 2 - Store value from method GET

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question. I'm new o Angular 2 and I tried to store a simple value in a variable. I call a get method that returns a number (backend in c#). How can I store this value on a global variable?

```
getTarea(a,b,c,d,e){
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:50790/ApiProductoTipo/TareaPT?delegacionId='+a+'&municipioId='+b+'&ejercicioId='+c+'&ninternoId='+d+'&tipo='+e)
             .map(res=> {alert('Tarea:'+res);})
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

This code print

> Tarea:Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:50790/ApiProductoTipo/TareaPT?delegacionId=11&municipioId=1&ejercicioId=2017&ninternoId=-1&tipo=T

But i need the number value that returns this method. Any ideas?

Back

```
[HttpGet]
public int GetTareaPT(int delegacionId, int municipioId, int ejercicioId, int ninternoId, string tipo)
{
    int numtarea = this.productoTipoService.GetTareaPT(delegacionId, municipioId, ejercicioId, ninternoId, tipo);

    if (numtarea != 0)
    {
        return numtarea;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you want the json: `.map(res=> {alert('Tarea:', res.json());})`

Comment: or the text: `.map(res=> {alert('Tarea:'+res.text());})`

Comment: @PierreDuc true, I always forget that one :D

Comment: That's works! Very grateful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to AJT_82 by doing

```
.map(res=> {alert('Tarea:', res.json());})
```